# PostgreSQL: Taking into account correlation between null / not null values of columns during planing

Tags: postgresql, optimization, execution-plan, postgresql-performance

**Question:**
Is PostgreSQL able to take into account correlation between null value of one column and not null values of other columns during planing? Does ["Cross Columns Stats"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Cross_Columns_Stats) feature allow achieving this?

**Context:**
This is mostly educational problem, but I run into it with production-like database.
I have a table `entity as e` that beside others has two columns: `e.parent_id` and `e.is_draft`. The first one is self-reference FK and the second one is business specific value. There is a strong dependency:

> If `e.parent_id is null` then `e.is_draft = false` almost sure. (assertion 1)

But generally speaking `is_draft=true` for ~52% of rows.

```
select tablename
     , attname
     , null_frac
     , most_common_vals
     , most_common_freqs  from pg_stats
where 1=1
  and tablename = 'entity'
  and attname in ('parent_id','is_draft');
```

| tablename | attname | null_frac | most_common_vals | most_common_freqs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| entity | is_draft | 0 | {t,f} | {0.52781,0.47218} |
| entity | parent_id | 0.38247567 | {2086,713,2060,...} | {0.04172,0.01668,0.00834,...} |

My table under test is small (<< 300*100 rows), so I expect that PostgreSQL has very accurate statistics and estimates rows correctly. For educational purposes, I am analyzing execution of the following query my backend typically generates using ORM:

```
explain analyse select e.id
                     , ...
                     , e.created_at
                     , e.is_draft
                     , e.name
                     , e.parent_id
                from entity e
                where (e.parent_id is null)
                  and e.is_draft=false
                order by e.created_at desc,
                         e.name desc
                limit 10 offset 3;
```

The `explain analyse` result is:

```
Limit  (cost=40.50..40.52 rows=10 width=81) (actual time=0.500..0.503 rows=10 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=40.49..41.14 rows=260 width=81) (actual time=0.498..0.500 rows=13 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: created_at DESC, name DESC"
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
        ->  Seq Scan on entity e  (cost=0.00..34.38 rows=260 width=81) (actual time=0.009..0.355 rows=535 loops=1)
              Filter: ((parent_id IS NULL) AND (NOT is_draft))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 903
Planning Time: 0.085 ms
Execution Time: 0.523 ms
```

I wonder why PostgreSQL missed rows estimation of Seq Scan + Filter (expected: `rows=260` vs actual: `rows=535`). As I guess, PostgreSQL estimation is 260 as

(`n_live_tup`) * (`null_frac` of `e.parent_id`) * (`most_common_freqs` of `e.parent_id=false`) = 1438 * 0.382 * 0.472 = 260

So PostgreSQL doesn't know of (assertion 1). Now I'd like to make it know of it:

```
create statistics entity_is_draft_parent_id (dependencies) on is_draft, parent_id from entity; 
analyze entity;
```

But after that, PostgreSQL estimation is still 260 rows. I can't fully understand what `{"6 => 3": 0.614743}` value of `pg_stats_ext.dependencies` means for created statistics, but I noticed that PostgreSQL treats `nulls` and actual values statistics differently for planning. If I drop FK constraint on `e.parent_id` and replace `null` values with `-1`, then `explain analyze` result will be:

```
        ->  Seq Scan on entity e  (cost=0.00..52.98 rows=438 width=81) (actual time=0.195..0.562 rows=535 loops=1)
```

Now, rows estimation error is about 18% against 51% for the first try.

So my question is why PostgreSQL 12 does not take into account cross column statistic when  `null` value is involved? What is a real life solution for this problem?